# How to Sort Div Content In Descending Order By Image Name?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to  sort a div by DESCENDING order based on their image name.

**Change From this:**

```
<div id="sort-this-div">
<p><img src="image/1.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/3.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/4.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/2.jpg"/></p>
</div>
```

**To This**

```
<div id="sort-this-div">
<p><img src="image/4.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/3.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/2.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/1.jpg"/></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using pure JavaScript. [**Check it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLUd7/6/)

```
var sort = document.getElementById('sort-this-div');
var imgs = sort.getElementsByTagName('img');

var i, img, sorted = [];
for(i = 0; (img = imgs[i]); i++){
    sorted.push(img.getAttribute('src'));
}
sorted = sorted.sort(function(a, b){
    return +b.match(/\/(\d+?)\.jpg/)[1] - +a.match(/\/(\d+?)\.jpg/)[1];
});

for(i = 0; (img = imgs[i]); i++){
    img.src = sorted[i];
}​
```

What this does, it copies all of the src paths for your images into the `sorted` variable, sorts them, and then updates all of the image's src paths with the new sorted order.

**UPDATE**

Added the custom sort function to address the problem brought up by @EugeneXa

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sort-this-div">
    <p><img src="image/1.jpg"/></p>
    <p><img src="image/3.jpg"/></p>
    <p><img src="image/4.jpg"/></p>
    <p><img src="image/2.jpg"/></p>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
/* as option:
function sort(container) {
    var images = [],
        paragraphs = container.getElementsByTagName('p');        
    while(!!paragraphs.length) {
        var p = paragraphs[0];
        images.push(p.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src'));
        container.removeChild(p);
    }
    images = images.sort();
    console.log(images);
    for(var i = images.length; i-- > 0;) {
        var p = document.createElement('p'),
            img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = images[i];
            p.appendChild(img);
        container.appendChild(p);
    }
}*/

function sort(container) {
    var images = [],
        imageSources = [],
        paragraphs = container.getElementsByTagName('p');        
    for(var i = paragraphs.length; i-- > 0;) {
        var img = paragraphs[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
            src = img.getAttribute('src');
        images.push(img);
        imageSources.push(src);
    }
    imageSources = imageSources.sort();
    console.log(imageSources);
    for(var i = imageSources.length; i-- > 0;) {
        images[i].src = imageSources[i];
    }
}

var container = document.getElementById('sort-this-div');
sort(container);
```

​

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/jWmXT/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort plugin for jquery http://qd9.co.uk/projects/jQuery-Plugins/sort/demo.html

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/PuUn5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p img").sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).attr('src') > $(b).attr('src') ? -1 : 1;
    });
});​
```

Comment: The only problem here is that "2.jpg" ends up being larger than "10.jpg", but I am not sure whether it needed to be sorted by numbers or alphabetically

Comment: True. As you can see, we are comparing the image src, not the image file name. The code can be updated to grab the image file name without extension and compare accordingly.

Comment: Now you are talking about complex regex stuff.  If you can, you should first rename your files to a sortable format using leading zeros.  In all honesty, `2.jpg` should always come after `10.jpg` much the same way that `b` will always come after `a` - you have to think like a computer and remember that these are strings... not integers buried within strings.